# Как преобразовать строку в байтовый массив

Tags: c, arduino

Есть строка IP-адрес. Как его преобразовать в byte array?

Comment: Что значит "есть строка". Приведите пример, что есть, и что вы хотите получить.

Comment: `inet_aton()` ?

Comment: Если у вас в Си есть строка - значит всё ок, массив байтов у вас тоже есть.

Comment: @Mike вы теги смотрели? Какой inet_aton. Вы о чем

Comment: @Radzhab Так я знак вопроса в конце поставил. Я ожидал, что вы подтвердите, что вам нужен аналог этой функции (могли бы в вопросе это указать, если это так, было бы проще понять чего вы хотите получить). А так то открываете исходники libc, смотрите там как сделана эта функция

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вы работаете с сокетами. Тогда обратите внимание на такие функции, как, например, `inet_aton` и другие, описанные, например, [здесь](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton).

Если же вас интересует чисто абстрактный вопрос, то можно написать что-то вроде

```
int a[4];
sscanf(addr,"%d.%d.%d.%d",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3]);
```

и проверить, чтоб были считаны именно 4 значения, и все они укладывались в диапазон 0-255...

Comment: Теги arduino. Тут не чистый c

Comment: Тогда уберите тег "C" :)

Comment: Вы оба путаете *Си* со *стандартной библиотекой Си*.